# Whats the purpose of the __thiscall keyword?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

When reading through the [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) there is a `thiscall` convention which purpose is pretty clear.

I understand that `thiscall` defines a function which is part of a class, because these functions require an object as their first hidden parameter for non-static functions.

So if I understand it right, then the following function have to be `thiscall`. The keyword doesn't need to be used because the compiler doesn't have much choice there and have to declare it as such.

```
 class Foo
 {
     public:
     int function(void) { return 1; }
 };
```

Now when I declare functions outside a class like this:

```
int __thiscall Otherfunction(void) { return 1; }
int __thiscall Otherfunction(Foo *t) { return 1; }
```

Then I get the compiler error:

> error C3865: '__thiscall': can only be used on native member functions

It even makes sense because how would you call these functions? So why does this keyword even exist if it can not be used? Or is there some usecase where this can/has to be used?

Comment: From the linked article: *The thiscall calling convention can only be explicitly specified on Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 and later. On any other compiler thiscall is not a keyword. (However, disassemblers, such as IDA, must specify it. So IDA uses keyword __thiscall for this.)*

Comment: @NathanOliver, I don't really understand why IDA would need it, except for documentation purposes. After all, other compilers also don't need it as it is implicitly done anyway.

Comment: Calling conventions are often operating system and target processor specific. An example is documented in [x86-64 ABI](https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/elf/x86_64-abi-0.99.pdf) specification for Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> these functions require an object as their first hidden parameter for non-static functions

Ironically, you half answered yourself, because what you describe here is called `fastcall`, not `thiscall`, an ancient alternative to call member functions. `thiscall` stores `this` in a register, not on the stack.

So that's your answer, not because `thiscall` can be used on non-member functions, but because you can use different conventions on member functions (`fastcall` and of course `nakedcall` or whatever it's called).

Comment: For completeness and accuracy sake, Microsoft's implementation of `fastcall` is slightly different, where it stores its first 2 arguments in registers instead of on the stack. In general though, `fastcall` uses the stack.

Comment: According to the article, `fastcall` seems not to be directly related to class members, though of course it may be possible that the `this` pointer is passed this way. But from the text it sounds that `fastcall` is generic, while `thiscall` is ONLY usefull for class members, but it's not even needed as a keyword.

Comment: There are two `fastcall` versions, one for members and one for non-members. `vectorcall` is a superset of the non-member `fastcall` only. And yes, `thiscall` is the default, but my point is that it can be overriden. And if you override the default, you need a way to specify `thiscall`, right? Hence, keyword!

Comment: Think of it this way, `int` is the default type, right? You never need to specify it, the (C) compiler assumes it automatically. When's the last time anyone has asked why `int` exists as a keyword?

Comment: Ah! I think I understand now. Because I can declare a member function like this `class A{ int __fastcall f(void);` thus explicitly overriding the `fastcall` if it were set as default.

Answer (score 3):

From the official [`__thiscall`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/thiscall?view=msvc-160) documentation.

> On ARM, ARM64, and x64 machines, `__thiscall` is accepted and ignored by the compiler. That's because they use a register-based calling convention by default.
>
> One reason to use `__thiscall` is in classes whose member functions use `__clrcall` by default. In that case, you can use `__thiscall` to make individual member functions callable from native code.
>
> When compiling with `/clr:pure`, all functions and function pointers are `__clrcall` unless specified otherwise. The `/clr:pure` and `/clr:safe` compiler options are deprecated in Visual Studio 2015 and unsupported in Visual Studio 2017.

This appears to imply that `__thiscall` is never required to be explicitly specified when writing plain C++ (unmanaged) code on ARM[64] or x86, or C++/CLI code in VC++ versions 2017 and later.

Answer (score 0):

As I found out because of the answers, the usecase where `__fastcall` makes sense is, when the default calling convention has been overriden by a compiler option and you need to have a function using the specific calling convention:

```
class Foo
{
 public:
    int __fastcall function(void) { return 1; }
};
```